# What does four (quadruple) curly braces do, or how does it even work?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on an existing ASP.NET MVC 5 codebase that uses some Angular (v1.2.22) binding with 4 curly braces in various spots in a partial view.  The code works, renders fine.  My dilemma is that I don't understand how it even works without rendering the curly braces to the browser.  For example:

```
<p>
    <label>@Localizer.ExteriorColor:</label>
    {{{{ vehicle.exteriorColor }}}}
</p>
```

It renders perfectly fine as "**Exterior Color: White**"
I'm baffled by this (hate not knowing why).  Can anybody explain this one to me?

Comment: I think this code is NOT html - it is preprocessed to html. So in html you will have {{vehicle.exteriorColor}}

Comment: You are dead on Petr.  Thank you.  After many breakpoints, I found where we're using SmartFormat to process the partial views to return the final IHtmlString.  The quadruple curly braces is how they've escaped curly braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved!  I found the spot in the code where the views are being handed off to a [SmartFormat](https://github.com/scottrippey/SmartFormat/) call and finally returning the IHtmlString. The quadruple curly braces is to escape them for SmartFormat.  Thanks to Petr Averyanov for the assist.